# Collectionview SubImages like PhotosApp

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I'm Trying to add thumbnails to contents on collectionview horizontal flowlayout like apple photos app as show below here.

[image]

what should I use for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have troubles with some specific feature or need a general advice on the technique to use?

Comment: yes actually I don't know what will I use for that Sub Images.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand you mean to say that you need to show a bunch of images and while moving from one image to another the background image would change accordingly.

*Style-1 :-*

You can take a collectionView on the bottom of the screen to show the thumbnail images and an imageView in the background and on `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` you can change ur background Image by setting it to the value at tapped indexPath.

*Style-2 :-*

You can take a "collectionView1" on the bottom of the screen to show the thumbnail images and another "collectionView2" behind it. While you tap on `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` (for "collectionView1") you can scroll the "collectionView2" to that indexPath so that it creates a feel that someone is swipping it using this :-

```
collectionView2.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(tappedIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

Check if you have set your delegate methods of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` correctly or not.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return sectionInsets 
    //returns the spacing between the cells, headers, and footers.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 5.0
            // spacing between items
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
            // spacing between lines
}
```

Also, don't forget to add constraints in collectionViewCell for the imageViews in it. Set top, bottom,trailing and leading constraint to 0. You can set it programmatically else through storyboard.

It will definitely workout. Remove your objects and add again along with your constraints. Clean and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

There you go, this will expand the cell on tap. Just replicate the functionality on `scrollViewDidEndDeacelerating`. The code is self explanatory just select the indexPath and reload the collection with `performBatchUpdates`:

```
//
//  CollectionViewController.swift
//  ExpandableCollection
//
//  Created by Marcos Griselli on 5/23/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 marcosgriselli. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    private var selectedPath: NSIndexPath?
    private var defaultSize: CGSize = CGSizeMake(40.0, 100.0)
    private var expandedSize: CGSize = CGSizeMake(80.0, 100.0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
        self.collectionView?.pagingEnabled = true
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 40
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: UICollectionView Delegate

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        selectedPath = nil

        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ 
            self.selectedPath = indexPath
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}

//MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        guard let selectedIndex = selectedPath else { return defaultSize }
        return selectedIndex == indexPath ? expandedSize : defaultSize
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.0
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm just show that images bottom of cell. I don't care about size of subimages.Just trying to show them bottom of cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure  your collectionView's  horizontal flowlayout right.You can use the flowing delegatemethod to recreate the effect  like Photos App.

```
var  selectedIndexPath :NSIndexPath?{
    didSet{
        if let indexpath = selectedIndexPath {
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexpath, atScrollPosition:  .CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
        }
    }
}    

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        return CGSizeMake(100, 50) // selected size
    }
    else{
        return CGSizeMake(50, 50)// default size
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
}

 // make sure the first and last cell is at the center of CollectionView most
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
    let  firstItemsize = self.collectionView(collectionView, layout: collectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section))

    let numberOfItemsInSection = self.collectionView(collectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: section)
    let lastItemSize = self.collectionView(collectionView, layout: collectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: numberOfItemsInSection-1, inSection: section))


    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, collectionView.frame.size.width/2-firstItemsize.width/2, 0, collectionView.frame.size.width/2-lastItemSize.width/2)
}

//MARK : - UIScrollViewDelegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    selectedIndexPath = nil;
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool){
    if !decelerate {
        var centerPoint = collectionView.contentOffset
        centerPoint.x += collectionView.frame.width/2
        centerPoint.y += collectionView.frame.height/2
        selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(centerPoint)
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView){
    var centerPoint = collectionView.contentOffset
    centerPoint.x += collectionView.frame.width/2
    centerPoint.y += collectionView.frame.height/2
    selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(centerPoint)
}
```

The only problem remain is the lineSpacing of the selectedItem.